# Laravel 5.1.9 Simple Authentication Password don't encrypt when registering

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I've seen tutorials using

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Seems fine, but it's not very customizable as almost everything is automated. For example, in my case I do not want /auth/ prefix in my URL, and I have a user table that will be slightly different.

... and for the sake of this question, I'm also looking to understand how to do things myself, not just rely on full automation.

So this is what my AuthController looks like now:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest;
use Input, Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

/**
 * Display registration.
 *
 * @return  Response
 */
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param   CreateUserRequest   $request
 * @param   User                $user
 * @return  Response
 */
protected function postRegister(CreateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    //$request->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    //$user->password = bcrypt($user->password);
    $user->create($request->all());
    return redirect('/');
}

/**
 * Dispay login page
 *
 * @return  Response
 */
public function getLogin()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}

/**
 * Attempt to login.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postLogin()
{
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
    else{
        //To do: Figure out how to pass a login failed error.
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}

public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
}
```

So far it seem to work great, except I can't test the postLogin method as all the passwords in the database are stored in plain text (not crypted). As you can tell by the commented lines of code in the postRegister method, I've tried a few things to attempt to crypt the password, but I can't seem to access the value that will be stored in the database.

I also know of the alternative way that was in the file initially:

```
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
```

... but I'm sure there must be another way than to manually hardcode every field one by one... which would also not use my CreateUserResquest validation file (I assume this as the default file also had a validator method I got rid of in lieu of the proper Request validator file)

In short, my question is: 
How can I crypt the password from the postRegister method ?.

Comment: I also (just) realized I redifined lots of the methods already in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth ... for no real reason. No need to point it out, I will clean that up when I'll solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Hash; //Add this
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest;
use Input, Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller{
}
```

Instead of bcrypt use hash($password).

```
 return User::create([
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'password' => bcrypt($data['password']), //change this to 'password' => Hash::make($datas['password'])
  ]);
```

Comment: I know I was long winded, but the whole point was that I wanted to remain object oriented and use the $user->create($request->all()); way and avoid hardcoding every field manually with the $data array. But point taken, I will use Hash::make() instead of bcrypt(). But my question remain. Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have the feeling this is a clean or a good way to encrypt the password without having to hardcode all the fields, but this is a working solution I came up with:

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param   CreateUserRequest   $request
 * @param   User                $user
 * @return  Response
 */
protected function postRegister(CreateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    //Extract the current password
    $arr = $request->all();
    $arr['password'] = Hash::make($arr['password']);
    $request->replace($arr); //Re-inject the new data array in the request

    $user->create($request->all());
    return redirect('/');
}
```

I will wait for comments & better answers if any. 
Also, if other people with the same question are reading this, I added "use Hash;" at the begining of the file.